# What's a quick way to convert a List<List<string>> to string[][]?

Tags: c#, list, arrays

.ToArray doesn't do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One quick variation on the existing answers, which uses a method group conversion instead of a lambda expression:

```
string[][] array = lists.Select(Enumerable.ToArray).ToArray();
```

In theory it'll be every so slightly faster, as there's one less layer of abstraction in the delegate passed to `Select`.

Remember kids: when you see a lambda expression of this form:

```
foo => foo.SomeMethod()
```

consider using a method group conversion. Often it won't be any nicer, but sometimes it will :)

Getting back to a `List<List<string>>` is easy too:

```
List<List<string>> lists = array.Select(Enumerable.ToList).ToList();
```

Comment: just for giggles, how about converting back to string[][]?

Comment: Up to now I did not realize the fact that using a method group saves one level of indirection - I never really thought about it and always interpreted it as a kind of syntactic sugar. +1 for this insight.

Comment: awarded for efficiency as well

Comment: @KevinDeus: Do you mean back to a `List<List<string>>`?

Comment: @Jon, yeah.. you heard what I meant..  Is there a quick way to convert it back?

Comment: @KevinDeus: I edited it into the answer when I asked the question, just in case I was right :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you want to use a method-group conversion for `Select` in C# 3.0, the generic type-arguments need to be specified explicitly since return type inference does not work on method groups in C# 3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Linq is the way to go on this one.

```
List<List<String>> list = ....;
string[][] array = list.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

to break it down a little more the types work out like this:

```
List<List<String>> list = ....;
IEnumerable<String[]> temp = list.Select(l => l.ToArray());
String[][] array = temp.ToArray();
```

Comment: well i may not have gotten the green check, but at least i beat jon skeet!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> myStrings;

myStrings.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

(LINQ rocks)